# How to insert LaTeX formulas in LibreOffice?

Tags: lyx, tools, open-office

I am using Libreoffice normally, but I need have Gauss Matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) in Libreoffice . I found that Latex can do that. I installed Lyx on Ubuntu. How can I write Gauss Matrix in Lyx? Also how can I export it to Libreoffice Writer?

Comment: try and press `Edit` on wikipedia, then you will see the equivalent `LaTeX` code.

Comment: I don't know where the problem is in LO Math with GausJordan.
Have you tried this: left (matrix{1 # 5 ## 2 # 4} ~ mline ~ matrix{7 ## 9} right )

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Please don't abandon LibreOffice just for this. You can insert LaTeX formulas directly using the [TexMaths extension](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/texmaths-1).

### Installation:

1. Download the extension at https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/texmaths-1
2. Open LibreOffice Writer, go to `Tools -> Extension Manager`, and select the file (*.oxt) just downloaded.
3. Close all instances of LibreOffice and start it again.

You'll see a new toolbar:

[image]

### Configuration:

`TexMaths` supports two image formats, PNG and SVG. In practice, PNG resolution is quite poor, you need to install the `dvisvgm` converter for SVG.

On Ubuntu, it's as simple as:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-extra-utils
```

and on Fedora, it's:

```
$ sudo dnf install texlive-dvisvgm
```

After you install it, go to `TexMaths` system configuration and provide the paths for `latex`, `dvipng` and `dvisvgm`. See the screenshot below for reference:

[image]

Finally, set the preferences to use SVG by default.

### Usage:

The new toolbar is pretty simple, discover it by yourself. There are a few tips I would like to share to improve productivity though.

- To edit a previously inserted formula, click on the image and on the correspondent toolbar button.
- Define shortcuts in the `Shortcuts` tab of the `TexMaths` system configuration, I'd suggest <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> since there is no predefined shortcut for this keyboard combination in LibreOffice.

Comment: Just a note: this plugin is quite fragile in LibreOffice so be prepared to save frequently. For example: the default SVG format produces objects that can be selected individually in LibreOffice and if you accidentally do so, the whole formula becomes uneditable.

Comment: First of all, thanks! This is really cool extension. One problem though - I'm unable to use non ASCII characters in my LaTeX formulas. For example I try to do `V_ц` which should compile to V with little ц at the bottom and to the right of V, but the compiled image doesn't show ц at all. I guess the underlying packages don't know how to handle Cyrillic alphabet properly. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @dKab, yes there is a way, go to TexMaths options, add this to the preamble `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}`, now add an equation with the code `V_\text{ц}`. Press "LaTeX" button (sometimes you have to resize the dialog window to see the button).

Comment: Great answer, TeXMaths is pretty decent if you *have* to use LO. Sometimes you have to resize the dialog window to see the "Compile to LaTeX" button. XeLaTeX compilation doesn't work for me but the preamble option is pretty powerful. TeXMaths alignment (vertical and horizontal) is even better than with the official LibreOffice Math.

Comment: The TexMaths solution does not work if you are using the snap version of LibreOffice because it does not have permission to access the /usr/ folder. Instead I use [Writer2Latex](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/writer2latex-1).

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that this plugin won't allow to type LaTeX in any colour other than black.

Comment: `dvisvgm` and `dvipng` in @juliohm's answer can be installed by using `sudo apt install [package name]` on Lubuntu 20.04. `sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils` did not install `dvisvgm` and `dvipng` for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a small piece of info to those installing it for the first time - I got errors such as "please check your configuration" and "can't find file tmpfile.bsl". Turns out I had set the paths wrongly. Here is an image of my configuration in case anyone else also faces the same issue - [TexMathsConfiguration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16P3Yp9FSJHKfcwkPIQw935NL8O0ftAfE/view?usp=sharing). (I use Ubuntu 20.0.4 and LibreOffice 6.4.7.2; I also ran `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-texmaths` while debugging; don't know if that helped or not)

Comment: It worked for me, however it created a whole bunch of useless metadata information for any Latex symbol. I fixed this by using the XeLatex compiler instead of Latex compiler (in the TexMaths settings)