# latex libreoffice preamble TexMaths extension

Tags: equations

I am currently using the texmaths extension to insert latex formulas into a powerpoint presentation.  (libreoffice impress).  I have to use \usepackage{braket}  for the equations to work.  the problem is, each time I go back to modify an equation, I have to re-insert \usepackage{braket} in the preamble.  Is there any way to fix this?  another option could be to prepare the entire presentation in latex, never tried it..

this answer is related:  [How to insert LaTeX formulas in LibreOffice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150503/how-to-insert-latex-formulas-in-libreoffice)